# Highcharts polar chart axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I have a categorical polar chart with 5 axes, and each axis has its own min/max range. I would like to configure both the axis labels and to add ticks to each individual axis.

1. The axis labels are drawn on the axis line itself, but I'd prefer them to be drawn slightly away from the line
2. There are no ticks on each axis, and I would like short ticks drawn on each axis line.

I've tried tinkering without success with the `gridLine*` and `tick*` y axis properties. Nothing seems to visually change when I do this, so I am guessing I'm barking up the wrong tree. Can I get tickmarks and better label positioning?

Here's a fiddle for this:  https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/cgrk96yh/

[image: Green lines are my tick preferences]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `chart.parallelAxes.labels` option to set `x` and `y` axis labels positions.

**Example code:**

```
chart: {
        polar: true,
        parallelCoordinates: true,
        parallelAxes: {
          gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
               y: 25,
            }
        },
      }
```

**API Reference**:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.parallelAxes.labels

2. There is no possibility to set ticks for the polar chart from the API options. You will need to draw them using Highcharts.SVGRenderer. Check the similar thread at Highcharts forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=45661

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer